# How do I use "<<" with my own struct?

Tags: c++, stl, sqlite, containers

I have following program to access sqlite database and to get the content of a table into a **LIST CONTAINER**.

All I want is to print the data which is in the list container.But I get this ERROR.

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘<<’ token
```

The below file is **DBAccess1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>

#include "DBAccess1.h"

bool sqliteDB::GET_ALL_Site_Code(list<SiteCode>& Site_Code_list)
{
        sqlite3 *db;
        const char *sql;
        sqlite3_stmt * stmt;

        int rc = sqlite3_open("/DBsqlite3/empdbv3.db", &db);

        sql = "SELECT * FROM SiteCode;";

        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, 0);

        while(sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {

             int column = sqlite3_column_count(stmt);

             for(int i = 0; i < column; i++)
             {
                 int A  = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
                 int B = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 1);

                 SiteCode info;
                 info.siteID = A;
                 info.siteCode = B;              

                 cout<<"Preparing to push data into List"<<endl;
                 Site_Code_list.push_back(info);
                 cout<<"Data was pushed successfully"<<endl;
             }//FOR LOOP ENDS HERE

        }// WHILE LOOP ENDS HERE

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return true;
}

//=================================XX=============================//

void sqliteDB::printList()
{

     int s = Site_Code_list.size();
     cout << "The size of List is :" << s << endl;

     for( list<SiteCode> :: iterator it = Site_Code_list.begin(); it !=  Site_Code_list.end(); it++)     

     cout << it* << " "; //The ERROR occurs here
```

}

Below is my **DBAccess.h** file:

```
#ifndef DBAccess1_HH
#define DBAccess1_HH

#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct SiteCode
{
  int siteID;
  int siteCode;
};

class sqliteDB {

public:

list<SiteCode> Site_Code_list;

bool GET_ALL_Site_Code(list<SiteCode>& Site_Code_list);

void printList();

};

#endif
```

And below is my **main.cpp** from where I am calling the functions:

```
int main()

{

    sqliteDB object1;

    list<SiteCode> Site_Code_list;

    object1.GET_ALL_Site_Code(Site_Code_list);

    object1.printList();

    cout << "\n\nAll the statement were executed properly\n\n";

   return 0;
}
```

The Error I get is:

```
   error: expected primary-expression before ‘<<’ token
   cout << it* << " ";
```

Comment: Well you can't multiply something by nothing.

Comment: @jsantander I just tried that but I get the same error.

Comment: @BoBTFish I did that too. But I get the following error:error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘SiteCode’)
      std::cout << *it << " ";

Comment: @chris : Could u please elaborate. I am new to STL

Comment: @K.K: The new error is because you haven't overloaded `operator<<` to work with your type. Either do that, or change `<< *it` to `<< it->siteID << ':' << it->siteCode` or something.

Comment: @MikeSeymour : I did tried to over load the << operator with it.c_str(). But I get another error that c_str() is not structure memeber of SiteCode. I checked my header file. but I still get same error.

Comment: @K.K, The only way * can come after an identifier (like `it`) is if it's being multiplied by something. Therefore, the compiler is looking for the other half of the multiplication, but instead finds an operator. Voila, "expected primary-expression before '<<'"

Comment: @K.K: Indeed, `it.c_str()` is nonsense. Doesn't your introductory book show you how to overload `<<` for your own types? It might look something like `ostream & operator<<(ostream & s, SiteCode const & sc) {return s << sc.siteID << ':' << sc.siteCode;}` depending on how you want it formatted.

Comment: @MikeSeymour The overloading that you suggested works. The error is gone. The data is getting pushed into list but am still unable to print it on terminal. The size of list it shows is 0.

Comment: @K.K: That's because you're pushing the data onto the local list you declare in `main`, then printing the member of `object1`, which is still empty. You need to decide whether the list should be part of the `sqliteDB` or separate, and stick to that decision.

Comment: @MikeSeymour : Overloading is confusing me at this moment. But I will definitely work on your suggestions.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: ohhh..ok now I can see what mistake i made. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two "errors" in your code. The first is the one that everyone else has pointed out. This

```
cout << it * << " ";
```

should be this

```
cout << *it << " ";
```

Which if course generates the second error

```
no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream
{aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘SiteCode’) 
std::cout << *it << " ";
```

Which is actually telling you *exactly* what the problem is. You are trying to output a `SiteCode` object onto the stream, but there is no `<<` operator defined for a `SiteCode` object.

You need to add the following for your `SiteCode` struct.

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, SiteCode &site)
{
    out << "(" << site.siteID << "," << site.siteCode << ")";
    return out;
}
```

Declare this in the header file, after the struct is defined, thus:

```
struct SiteCode
{
  int siteID;
  int siteCode;
};

inline ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, SiteCode &site)
{
    out << "(" << site.siteID << "," << site.siteCode << ")";
    return out;
}
```

And now you will be able to use `<<` with any `SiteCode` object on any stream.

How you actually format the output of the object is up to you. I just chose to display it as a tuple.

Comment: ohhh..ok now I can see what mistake i made. I will try this right away. Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually, don't make it a member of `SiteCode`. been a while since I did this. Just define the operator at file scope (outside the struct definition) -updated

Comment: I get this message- /tmp/ccaVupP5.o: In function `operator<<(std::ostream&, SiteCode&)':
DBAccess1.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `operator<<(std::ostream&, SiteCode&)'
/tmp/ccAfO840.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 1):

#### Introduction

Dereferencing an iterator is done with `*it`, not `it*` - the latter would expect another operand; "multiplication of `it` and *primary-expression*".

```
cout << *it << " "; // fixed
```

---

#### Note

The previous *"fix"* will require you to define a `operator<<` suitable for `std::cout`, and an object of type `SiteCode`.

If you just want to print the list in a simple manner you can do the following:

```
cout << it->siteID << " " << it->siteCode << "\n";
```

Comment: I did that too. But I get the following error:error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘SiteCode’) std::cout << *it << " ";

Comment: That's a different error; and as the compiler is saying.. there's no suitable overload for printing an object of type `SiteCode`.

Comment: The overloading that you suggested works. The error is gone. The data is getting pushed into list but am still unable to print it on terminal. The size of list it shows is 0. But now I know (thanks to MikeSeymour). it is because I declared my list into main(). Which is local. then printing the member of object1, which is still empty.

Comment: But thank you so much. I truly appreciate the information you provided. I did not knew the method that you suggested.

Comment: I accept your answer as well. It solved my problem. Thank you.